# Long running DOM update process in a React lifecycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl

I have one React component that contains two maps built with Mapbox GL.
These are left and right maps.

Component receives props like `leftMapData` and `rightMapData` independently when data is fetched from server and passed through Redux store.

Inside `componentDidUpdate()` I check if new props are different from what there was before and run some Mapbox GL map updating routine which can take some seconds.

As I notice, if two or more `componentDidUpdate` events happen quickly, like, almost instantly, one after another, then first map update is somehow cancelled and maps don't update properly.

How do I make sure that updating procedure is not cancelled by next update?

Props sometimes come for one map only, then I need to update only that one. Sometimes props come for both maps and I need to update each of them independently, not breaking another one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` method to control updation in your component.

`shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    // This function should return a boolean, whether the component should re-render.
    //Recommended - Do not do deep equality checks or using JSON.stringify() 
    //to avoid performance issues
    return false;
  }`